# grabbing a specific word from a loop/print

Tags: python, variables, web-scraping

Trying to grab a specific name within a print out. As of now, the code goes like this...

```
links = page_soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class' : 'gameLinks'})
for div in links:
    print div.find('a')['href']
```

The above code grabs all the links, giving me roughly 50 links and I just want a few that contain the word "redzone" within the url. Below is an example of the links that have redzone in them.

```
http://example.com/247075/1/nfl-redzone-live---never-miss-a-touchdown-live-stream-online.html
http://example.com/247075/2/nfl-redzone-live---never-miss-a-touchdown-live-stream-online.html
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: `link_href = div.find('a')['href']; if 'redzone' in link_href: print link_href`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the if "substring" in string, to see if a string contains a substring:

```
links = page_soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class' : 'gameLinks'})
for div in links:
    link = div.find('a')['href']
    if "redzone" in link:
        print link
```

You could also use regex as this is case-sensitive, it is more complicated but much more powerful!
https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html

Comment: That did the trick - thank you so much. Quick question, how can I append that print into a csv file without writing over what I already have? meaning, before this line of code, I've already printed to a csv file and would like to print the next code into the same csv file without overwriting it. :)

Comment: I would add everything to some data object first, like an array or dict, then at the very end of the program output to CSV. I don't have too much experience with CSV files but I would only write to the file once if I could. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into that. As for the "redzone" phrase, is it case sensitive?

Comment: Ya using this way is case sensitive. You have two options tho, you could convert to link variable to lowercase first before the search or take a look at regex, regex is a bit more complicated but much more powerful, I updated my answer to reflect this!